# Posting questions timeout

Tags: bug, locked-posts

I ran into a glitch with posting questions. I added more than five tags to my question which an error message told me when I tried to post. The problem is that when I removed a tag and tried to submit my question again the 90 minute lockout came up. This means it recorded my first post even though it failed and caused me to wait 90 minutes for no reason.

Comment: When exactly did you get that error? Just a few minutes ago? Longer? Because you have a question that was literally _just_ posted on SO. Are you on a shared network, i.e. at work or school? The 90 minute limit is per IP, not account, so someone else posting on your network would come up as the same IP in SO's eyes, thus causing the lockout.

Comment: Yes I just posted it. I got the error, wrote this post, then went back to SO and it worked.

Comment: Are you on a shared network, though? Because that could _still_ very well explain the issue. The 90 minutes in the message does not change to reflect the _actual_ time left until a new question can be asked, so it could be that you hit the error just on the tail end of the time limit, and only didn't see that error the first time because the tag check was done first.

Comment: Yes I am on a large corporate network so I'm going to assume that was the issue.